# WHERE clause IN group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ','),
    count(*) FROM users GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```

Is it possible to only concat the job fields that do not contain '', and if so how to? I can't do a WHERE clause, because I still need to ones that don't have a 'job'.

Picture the following table:

```
+-------+----------+
| name  | job      |
+-------+----------+
| Bob   | doctor   |
| Bob   | teacher  |
| Frank | dentist  |
| Tom   |          |
| Tom   |          |
| Tom   |          |
| Tom   |          |
| Tom   | salesman |
+-------+----------+
```

The current query would result in:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| name   | GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ',') | count(*) |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| Bob    | doctor, teacher                 | 2        |
| Frank  | dentist                         | 1        |
| Tom    | ,,,,salesman                    | 5        |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

But I want it to be:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| name   | GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ',') | count(*) |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
| Bob    | doctor,teacher                  | 2        |
| Frank  | dentist                         | 1        |
| Tom    | salesman                        | 5        |
+--------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

(Don't mind the logic of this table. It is just a simple example to make things clear)

Reason for this is, I am going to explode() the GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ',') in php, and in the actual table, there will easily be 1000 useless ,,'s and this would make the explode function very slow.
Thanks,

lordstyx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution: instead of making the job '', I'll just make the field Null, and the query ignores it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `IF()`:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT( if(job = '', null, job) SEPARATOR ','),
    count(*) FROM users GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(job SEPARATOR ',') FROM USERS
    WHERE job IS NULL OR job NOT LIKE '%,%'
    GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```

However, you might be better advised to string replace the comma to something else and then include all the jobs:

```
 SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(job, ',', ';')) FROM USERS
    GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: I've updated the original question a bit, because that's not really what I mean. Thanks anyways